# SELECT переменная FROM table WHERE id = 1 | Sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

Мне надо выбрать информацию в определенном столбце, который меняется в зависимости от переменной

```
cur.execute("""SELECT ? FROM achivs WHERE user_id = ?""", (name, user_id,))
```

насколько я понимал так оно не работает, ну или как минимум не корректно. Какие вообще есть способы это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT CASE ?
       WHEN 'column1' THEN column1
       WHEN 'column2' THEN column2
-- ...
       WHEN 'columnN' THEN columnN
       ELSE NULL
       END AS dynamic_column
FROM table
WHERE {conditions}
```

Comment: кстати забыл написать как также сделать с UPDATE

Comment: @5iqman А какая разница-то?

Comment: cur.execute("""UPDATE achivs SET CASE ? WHEN 'a' THEN aWHEN 'b' THEN b END = ? WHERE user_id = ?""", (name, True, user_id,)) как это починить пишет ошибка у CASE

Comment: @5iqman `... SET column1 = CASE ? WHEN 'column1' THEN ? ELSE column1 END, column2 = CASE ...`